# Get three vectors to form a base

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Be the vector space  of ${\rm I\!R}^5$ and the vectors (1, 2, 0, 2, 3) and (5, 3, 0, 3, 0) of said space:

> I'm trying to get three other vectors that, together with the two
>   previous ones, form a basis of the vector space ${\rm I\!R}^5$.

Comment: For example, you can use the algorithm to find orthogonal vectors to the two vectors you already have (those will be basis of the orthogonal complement for the subspace generated by your vectors). All of these together will be some basis of $\mathbb{R}^5$.

Comment: @RadekSuchánek If we consider $v_2-5v_1=(0,-7,0,-7,-15)$ then v_1 and v_2 with $e_3$,$e_4$ and $e_5$ are linearly independent . We don't need GS which is quite complex and time consuming.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Completing a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1533089/completing-a-basis-for-mathbbr4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Let consider the matrix with the $2$ given vectors as row and row reduce, then add the $e_i$ linearly independent vectors from the standard basis.

Comment: thanks for answering, I have managed to get the reduced by rows and get the identity matrix of order 5.

Comment: @peterxd4 see my comment above, if we consider $v_2-5v_1=(0,-7,0,-7,-15)$ then v_1 and v_2 with $e_3$,$e_4$ and $e_5$ are linearly independent .

Comment: why are they linearly independent?

Comment: Refer to the standard basis, that is $e_3=(0,0,1,0,0),e_4=(0,0,0,1,0),e_5=(0,0,0,0,1)$. Can you see why those are LI with $v_1$ and $v_2$?

Comment: I understand! and for what purpose do v2-5v1 ??

Comment: @peterxd4 to see that you have pivots in position 1 and 2, thus we are sure that $e_3$,$e_4$ and $e_5$ work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74995/discussion-between-peterxd4-and-gimusi).

Comment: I already understand, thank you very much !!

Comment: @peterxd4 You are welcome! Bye