# Proof of the unicity of a linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, vectors

How do I demonstrate that if $y$ is a linear combination of independent vectors $x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_n $then the set of coefficients $c_1,c_2,\dotsc,c_n$ is unique?

Comment: There’s a standard way to show something is unique: take two arbitrary such things and show they are equal. Here that thing is a tuple (not set) $(c_1,\ldots,c_n)$.

Comment: Is $n$ the dimension of your ambient vector space ? Or the dimension may be $>n$ ? If the answer to the second question is yes, then "complete" $\{x_1,\cdots x_n\}$ by vectors in such a way that altogether they constitute a basis  (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/686217/completing-two-vectors-into-a-basis-of-mathbb-r4). Then reason on the existence and unicity of the decomposition of a vector onto a basis.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Suppose that 
$$
y=c_1x_1+c_2x_2+\dotsb +c_nx_n
$$
and 
$$
y=d_1x_1+d_2x_2+\dotsb+ d_nx_n
$$
are two different ways of writing $y$ as a linear combination of the $x_i$.  Subtract the two equations and use the linear independence of the $x_i$.

Comment: You assume  that $n$ is the dimension of the ambient vector space, but the OP doesn't say anything about it (see my remark)